# Is it possible to parse an environmental variable as a response for a REST API?

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have a REST API created on integration studio, I send back a response using the following tag:

```
 <format> "Some response" </format>
```

Is is possible to set an environmental variable as the response? So that I can change my response without having to redeploy the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the get-property expression in the Payload factory to read the response from an environment variable as follows,

```xml
<payloadFactory media-type="text">
    <format>"$1"</format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('env', 'property_name')"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

Depending on your requirement you may need to change the `media-type` as well.

For more information about `PayloadFactory` mediator check the following official docs
https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/payloadFactory-Mediator/